# Branching rules for $SU(3)$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, group-theory, group-representations, lie-algebra, representation-theory

How does one compute the [branching rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restricted_representation) for $SU(3)\to SU(2)\times U(1)$.?

In particular, I do not know how to put the abelian charges.

Take for example the adjoint $\mathbf{8}$ of $SU(3)$.

I can see it decomposes as $\mathbf{8}\to\mathbf{3}+2\cdot\mathbf{2}+\mathbf{1}$.

But how do I figure out the representations of the $U(1)$ factor?

Furtheremore, does a general procedure, or a specific computer program exist in order to compute these branching rules? For example, how would one go with computing the branching rules of $SU(5)$?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/587761/11127, which mentions a software package [LieArt](http://lieart.hepforge.org/). See also the software package [LiE](http://wwwmathlabo.univ-poitiers.fr/~maavl/LiE/).

Comment: This question (v2) seems like an archetype of a math problem encountered in many areas of physics, e.g. QCD, and which the community consistently wants to _not_ migrate to Math.SE, cf. [this meta post](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/5713/2451).

Comment: @Qmechanic Agreed, I'd like to see this answered here.

Comment: @Qmechanic. Sorry, I don't understand what you said. Should I have posted this in math.SE?

Comment: Well, people on Phys.SE are divided over the issue. Do you want me to migrate it to Math.SE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll use a notation that probably you know. I'll denote group representations by Dynkin labels.
Consider the following:
\begin{equation*}
[1,0]_3 = [1]_2 q^1 + [0]_2q^0 \ ,
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
[0,1]_3 = [1]_2 q^{-1} + [0]_2q^0 \ .
\end{equation*}
Where $q$ is the $U(1)$-charge of the representation.
By Dynkin diagrams the $SU(3)$ algebra can be represented as
0---0 and the reflection symmetry correspond to the complex conjugation. Thus, we know the adjoint rep $[1,1]_3$ to be real, because it takes $\boldsymbol{3}$ and its conjugate $\boldsymbol{\bar{3}}$ on the same foot; this reasoning applies also to the Abelian charge. Thus, this manifests into decomposition as follows
\begin{equation*}
[1,1]_3 = [2]_2 q^0 + [1]_2 \left(q^1 + q^{-1}\right) + [0]q^0 \ .
\end{equation*}

Comment: I may be mistaken, but the $U(1)$ charges here do not look quite right: they should sum to $0$ in any representation $R$ of $SU(3)$, since $\mbox{Tr}_R(T)=0$ for any generator $T$ in $SU(3)$, in particular for the generator of $U(1)$.  The $U(1)$ charges given here seem to be charges under a linear combination of the $U(1)$ in $SU(3)$ and the $U(1)\simeq U(3)/SU(3)$.  That piece cancels out in real representations such as the adjoint, but not in the fundamental/antifundamental representations.  (Oh, and I fixed a minor typo.)