# Decomposing a representation under a subgroup

Tags: group-theory, group-representations, lie-algebra, representation-theory

I am trying to understand what is the method for decomposing representations of a group under one of its subgroups. I already had a look in [Slansky](http://inspirehep.net/record/10204), but I could not extract a concrete set of rules/algorithm about how this works. Could someone provide this algorithm or maybe just even discuss an example?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/159597/2451

Comment: This question (v2) seems like an archetype of a math problem encountered in many areas of physics, e.g. QCD, and which the community consistently wants to _not_ migrate to Math.SE, cf. [this meta post](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/5713/2451).

Comment: I edited this question so that it's not homework-like anymore. Could someone please reopen it or at least explain better the reasons for keeping it on hold? Thanks

Comment: Well, the community is divided over math questions such as this. If we re-open the question, it would likely receive 5 migration-votes for migration to Math.SE. Do you want to migrate it to Math.SE?

Comment: I would prefer the question stayed in physics.SE and I genuinely believe such questions do belong here. However, it's not much use having it on hold, so I propose to reopen it and if it gets the migration-votes, so be it...

Comment: @Heterotic did you find an answer/ a good resource on the topic in the meantime? Would be very interested and don't really understand why this question got closed

Comment: @Tim After some digging, I found these notes useful: http://www.maths.liv.ac.uk/TheorPhys/RESEARCH/STRING_THEORY/journal_club/will18Feb2013.pdf

Comment: The question is answered at https://www.physicsoverflow.org/26079/decomposing-a-representation-under-a-subgroup?show=45542#a45542